# Overbrace height adjustment

Tags: equations

I have a set of equations which I'd like to annotate with overbraces (or anything else at your discretion). However they are fixed to the top of each individual item which they reference, which looks messy. Can I make them all at a fixed height above the equations?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
\overbrace{\dfrac{\partial\rho \mathbf{U}}{\partial t}}^{\text{time derivative}}+\overbrace{\mathbf{U}\cdot \nabla \rho\mathbf{U}}^{\text{advection}}=&\overbrace{-\nabla P}^{\text{pressure gradient}}+\overbrace{\mu\nabla^2\mathbf{U}}^{\text{diffusion}}+\overbrace{\rho \mathbf{g}}^{\text{body force}},&\quad \text{\emph{momentum eq.}}\label{eq:mom}\\
   \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot \rho\mathbf{U}=&\, 0,&\quad \text{\emph{continuity eq.}}\label{eq:cont}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\overbrace{\rule{0pt}{2cm}......}` will raise them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a phantom to the contents of `\overbrace`; here's a command `\xoverbrace` that takes an optional argument (default a big fraction) for finer adjustments. I also added a handier way to typeset partial derivatives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xoverbrace}[2][\vphantom{\dfrac{A}{A}}]{\overbrace{#1#2}}
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
\xoverbrace{\pder{\rho\mathbf{U}}{t}}^{\text{time derivative}}+
\xoverbrace{\mathbf{U}\cdot \nabla \rho\mathbf{U}}^{\text{advection}}
&=
\xoverbrace{-\nabla P}^{\text{pressure gradient}}+
\xoverbrace{\mu\nabla^2\mathbf{U}}^{\text{diffusion}}+
\xoverbrace{\rho \mathbf{g}}^{\text{body force}},
&&\text{\emph{momentum eq.}}\label{eq:mom}
\\
\pder{\rho}{t}+\nabla\cdot \rho\mathbf{U}
&=
0
&&\text{\emph{continuity eq.}}\label{eq:cont}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fancy-dancy! Thank you! :) Would this be your choice of annotating equations by the way? Looks nice, but I was wondering...

Comment: @HCAI I surely wouldn't use `\overbrace`, probably opting for a successive description of the terms.